# "A value is trying to be set ..."

Tags: passive-voice

I've got this message from a quite respectful software library:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

Shouldn't it be something in passive voice, like "The value is being tried to be set.."?

Comment: Why do you think it should be passive voice?

Comment: well,  to my russian ears "value is trying" sounds like it's value itself is undertaking something to be set

Comment: You are right, "value" is not the author of the try. Another formulation could be "There was an attempt to set a value on ..."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passive of "tried to eat"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49515/passive-of-tried-to-eat) // You can't passivise directly. 'An attempt is being made to set a value on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame' is a valid (grammatical and synonymous) passive sentence.

Comment: I guess it does, although I'm not much into grammar and actually meant to ask if the text sounds weird for native english speaker too

Comment: A morsel of food cannot try to be eaten.  I don't know any native speaker who uses such a construction. You can say this:  "A pile of bricks was waiting to be laid" but not "A pile of bricks was trying to be laid" — not if you want to make sense, that is.

Comment: The "respectability" of a software library doesn't mean that its help messages were authored (or edited) by a  fluent native speaker.

Comment: ok, thank you! :)